# Return user's latitude and longitude asynchronously

Tags: ios, xcode, cllocationmanager

```
func getCurrectLocationInfo()-> String {

    var strFormattedAddress : String = ""
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    var currentLoc: CLLocation!
    if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse ||
    CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways) {
       currentLoc = locationManager.location
       print(currentLoc.coordinate.latitude)
       print(currentLoc.coordinate.longitude)
        let latString = String(currentLoc.coordinate.latitude)
        let longString = String(currentLoc.coordinate.longitude)

    }
    self.getaddress(pdblLatitude: latString, withLongitude: longString) { address in
        print(address)
        strFormattedAddress = address

        return strFormattedAddress
    }
}
```

How to return the current lat long of the user asynchronously. Please guide. Here in above code it is returning empty string

Comment: Don't you get `Use of unresolved identifier` error for `latString` and `longString`?

Comment: It's not the similar question which you marked.

Comment: It is. You try to return something from an asynchronous task. The API is different but the issue is exactly the same.

Comment: every asynchronous task or thing is not same, you can't define everything under same name

Comment: An escaping completion handler is an escaping completion handler regardless of the used parameter types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function is asynchronous, you need to modify your function with a completion block, like this:

```
func getCurrectLocationInfo(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {

    var strFormattedAddress : String = ""
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    var currentLoc: CLLocation!
    if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse ||
    CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways) {
       currentLoc = locationManager.location
       print(currentLoc.coordinate.latitude)
       print(currentLoc.coordinate.longitude)
        let latString = String(currentLoc.coordinate.latitude)
        let longString = String(currentLoc.coordinate.longitude)

    }
    self.getaddress(pdblLatitude: latString, withLongitude: longString) { address in
        print(address)
        strFormattedAddress = address
        completion(strFormattedAddress)
    }
}
```

And you need to call it like this:

```
LocationManager.shared.getCurrectLocationInfo) { locationInfo in 
    strPlaceSearched = locationInfo
}
```

Comment: Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion'

Comment: Check now, I've just updated.

Comment: can you please guide what's wrong in my call "strPlaceSearched = LocationManager.shared.getCurrectLocationInfo(completion
            {success in
                
        })"

Comment: Did it work? I'd added how to use the method in my answer.

Comment: i have fixed the calling method issue myself as well.